# jQuery ajax call not working on my site

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-ui

I want the content of my page to appear in a main content window on my site via AJAX... at least this way I can add some cool effects to it with jquery such as toggle/hide/slide etc... the issue I am having at the moment is getting the ajax call to work properly. Can someone review the code below and tell me where I went wrong?  much appreciated.

```
$( "#serviceOffered" ).click(function(){

        $.ajax({

            url : "ajax/getPage.php",
            type : POST, 
            async : true,   
            success : function(result){
                $( "#contentMain" ).html(result);
            }
        })  
    })
```

HTML Code

```
<ul id="menu" style="font-size:14px; width:170px; margin-top:40px; margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <li><a href="#" id="serviceOffered">Services Offered</a></li>
</ul> <div id="contentMain"></div>
```

getPage.php

```
<?php echo "test get page"; ?>
```

Comment: Check your network activity when this call is supposed to fire (Console -> Network Tab in Chrome) -- Is the request going through? Also, can you post the relevant parts from `getpage.php`?

Comment: @tymeJV - thank you. the message from chrome is "POST is not defined". what does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have `type : POST`, you missed out the quotes `type : "POST",`. Which means you were trying to pass a variable instead of a string. I'm guessing `POST` is undefined in this instance.